# For a special matrix $A_{n,k}(l)$ , show if $\det(A_{n,k}(l))=0$, then there exist a $\pi \in R_{++}^{nk}$ such that $A_{n,k}(l)\pi=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $n$ and $k$ be two positive integers, with $n \geq 2$ and $k \geq 1$. Let $l=\{{l_i}\}$ be an $nk$-dimensional positive real vector. Let $A_{n,k}(l)={(a_{i,j})}_{1 \leq i,j \leq nk}$ be the following $nk \times nk$ matrix:
\begin{equation}
a_{i,j}=
\begin{cases}
l_i&\text{if }\quad i=j,\\
-1&\text{if }\quad 1 \leq j-i \leq n-1,\\
-1&\text{if }\quad i \geq nk-n+2\ \text{ and }\ j+nk-i \leq n-1,\\
0&\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
That is,
$$
A_{n,k}(l) = \pmatrix{
l_1 & -1 & \cdots &-1 &0 &\cdots &0\\
0 & l_2 & -1 &\ddots &-1 &\ddots &\vdots\\
\vdots & 0 & l_3 &-1 &\ddots &\ddots &0\\
0 &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &-1\\
-1 &0 &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\ddots &\vdots \\
\vdots& \ddots& \ddots&\ddots&0&l_{kn-1}&-1\\
-1 & \cdots & -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0  & l_{kn}},
$$

where the lower triangular bottom-left block has size $(n-1)\times(n-1)$.
I want to show if $\det(A_{n,k}(l))=0$, then there exist a $\pi \in R_{++}^{nk}$ such that $A_{n,k}(l)\pi=0$.

Comment: What exactly is $R^{nk}_{++}$?

Comment: It is a nk-dimension space with all dimension be strictly positive.